# Topological space (or math structure more generally) without encoding as set

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Given the historical development of modern mathematics, everything is ultimately encoded as a set (possibly with some additional structure, also encoded as set(s) ). For example, a topological space is an ordered pair $(X, \tau)$ where $X$ is the underlying point-set and $\tau$ is a set of subsets on $X$ called it's topology, obeying some axioms. But what if I don't care about sets in particular, especially just the sets of ZFC, what if I want to study mathematical structures with notions of nearness, connectedness, continuity, etc. and do not want to be constrained to an underlying set theoretic encoding? Does category theory offer me a way to study the "essence" of a topological space that will hold no matter what encoding (i.e. foundational theory) I use?

Comment: Topoi might be what you're looking for. Here's the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos

Comment: You might want to look at Peter Johnstone's paper on "The point of pointless topology".

Comment: I somehow feel that this question is the embodiment of the whole "scared of ZFC" philosophy that we are seeing more and more by people who were not exposed to set theory or classical foundations properly in their studies. This is very much how I read the remark "especially just the sets of ZFC". It's as though sets form some psychological barrier in some people. And that is truly a shame. I'm not saying that everyone should be a set theorist or even know set theory. But it seems like a particularly ignorant comment to make, in a setting that feels more and more "normal" in today's mathematics.

Comment: What's wrong with "the sets of ZFC" (what a weird expression !), and with topological spaces ? Topological spaces are precisely designed to study all these notions of connectedness, continuity, etc... It is not the starting point, but the conclusion of a very long historical process to formalize real analysis. What you need is a good book about the history of mathematics. The notion of topological space has various generalizations, Grothendieck topologies, locales more adapted to other parts of mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at locales?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I recognize your concern about seemingly disparaging set theory. That is not my point at all. ZFC set theory is but one of many possible universes for mathematics, and the sets of that theory to be one of many possible objects to study. As someone with a more computer science inclination, I'm more interested in encoding-agnostic structures. For example, if I want to study the topology of images, I don't want to have to think in terms of sets, I just want to think in terms of abstract relations between images, irrespective of the encoding.

Comment: Then what does set theory even has to do with it? Just study topological structures. People think that ZFC is this sort of rigid and concrete thing that is completely inflexible on how you code things. It's not. In fact, it's even more coding agnostic than category theory in some extent, since the Replacement schema is exactly equivalent to saying that any coding that satisfies the ordered pair property can be used to code ordered pairs (and Replacement is absent from ETCS, for example). So yeah, pretty much go Nike and "Just Do It". Why even bother about your underlying set theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila While I agree it's not fair to disparage ZFC, it's disingenuous to suggest that the absence of replacement in ETCS somehow makes it less coding agnostic than ZFC.  In fact coding agnosticism is *built into* ETCS at a much more basic level, so there is no need for a complicated argument using a powerful axiom such as replacement.

Comment: When I talk about category theory, I usually remark about my relative discomfort with it, not to disparage the subject but to indicate my preference for a certain environment in which to think about mathematics.  However, some have seen these remarks as disparaging or insulting.  I suspect the poster is in a somewhat similar situation, where (as a poor analogy with no insult intended anywhere ) he is looking for a more comfortable/appropriate development environment than COBOL for his efforts.  Gerhard "Imagine Mathematics Developing From RATFOR" Paseman, 2017.07.16

Comment: @Mike: Maybe I don't know enough about ETCS, then. But it seems to me that if it is bi-interpretable with Z, and Z is missing Replacement, then perhaps it is not as-coding-agnostic-as-you'd-think, but rather the language used to talk about sets is more limited than that of material set theory. But again, I am completely ignorant about structural set theory issues, so I will take your word on that issue.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Coding-agnosticism (i.e. isomorphism-invariance) has nothing to do with consistency strength, so bi-interpretability doesn't tell you anything about it.  When ETCS is formulated properly in a dependently typed language, then there is a theorem that everything you can say in it is invariant under isomorphism, and in particular invariant under replacing any cartesian product by any other cartesian product.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to understand this question, leading to different answers.

1. If the question is about studying *topological spaces*, in the sense of points equipped with open sets, independent of a particular axiom system for set theory, then the commentators are right: ordinary point-set topology is (like nearly all of mathematics) already independent of any particular axiom system for set theory.
2. If the question is about studying things that behave like topological spaces but don't have a "set of points", then the other commentators are right that you should look into locales and topoi.
3. If the question is about "notions of nearness, connectedness, continuity" in a more general setting that are *not* necessarily defined in terms of a notion of "open set", then you may be interested in categorical topology (e.g. [topological categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category)) or [axiomatic cohesion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive+topos).

Comment: For statement 1, could you clarify what you mean by saying "ordinary point-set topology is..already independent of any particular axiom system for set theory", in light of the fact that so much of the (serious) theory of point-set topology makes use of extra-ZFC principles such as diamond,  CH, MA or large cardinals. We now know that many questions, concerning whether every such-and-such kind of space is also that kind and so on, are independent of ZFC and require these extra axioms to settle them. So even the ZFC-style versions of point-set topology seem to depend on the set-theoretic system.

Comment: In other words, what we've learned in point-set topology is that many fundamental topological questions do depend on one's set theoretic background.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Two answers.  The first is that I was not thinking about such questions at all, which I regard as rather esoteric.  Certainly I believe that if you spend enough time studying point-set topology as a field in its own right you will run into them soon enough, but for someone who primarily wants a tool to study "notions of nearness, connectedness, continuity" in "naturally occurring" spaces (which is what I assumed the OP wanted) I think they will not play much role.

Comment: The second answer is that such "extra-ZFC axioms" are not specific to ZFC: most of them have equally natural formulations in any other foundational set theory like ETCS.  So while point-set topology is not independent of the axioms of your set theory, it is independent of how you choose to formalize that set theory, and in particular of whether you use global-membership-based sets, categorical-structural sets, h-sets in HoTT, etc.

Comment: I like your second answer much better, and that is one I can agree with. My  point wasn't about ZFC specifically, but rather with the claim you seemed to make that topological questions don't depend on one's foundation, since we know that they definitely do. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_topology for a start. This is not esoteric, but rather an active field of mathematical research, with its own conferences and so on and connected with other fields. As you say, the extra hypotheses can of course be expressed in any sufficiently robust foundational system.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins By "esoteric" I didn't mean to be disparaging, or imply that it isn't interesting or doesn't have lots of people studying it.  All of pure mathematics is pretty esoteric to the man on the street.  (-:  I just meant that point-set topology is *used* by lots of people doing algebraic topology, low-dimensional topology, differential geometry, etc., and I don't think any of them have ever had any occasion to worry about large cardinal axioms.

Answer (score 2):

- Some categories are not concrete, i.e. one cannot think to objects as sets and to morphisms as function. It's the case of homotopy category of topological space.
- Sober spaces are equivalent to localic toposes with enough points but honestly, I am not sure this is so far from a set theoretic approach.